# Pinpointing a ResultSet with find_all

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use find_all to grab anything within a 'span' tag that is also the direct child of an 'a' tag and has the `itemprop="foo"` attribute. I'm using bs4. See below.

```
text = '<a><span itemprop="foo"> TEXT I WANT </span></a> \
<label><span itemprop="foo"> DO NOT WANT </span></label> \
<a><span itemprop="foo"> I WANT THIS TOO </span></a> \
<strong><a> DO NOT WANT </a></strong> \
<label><span itemprop="foo"> DO NOT WANT </span></label>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
```

My code looks like:

```
for stuff in soup.find_all("span", attrs={"itemprop" : "foo"}):
    print stuff.text
```

This pulls out all 4  pieces of text within the span tags, not just 2. I've made a number of attempts to add the 'a' tag to that syntax, but I can't get anything to work. What is the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround for this is to find all of the anchor tags using `anchor_tags = soup.find_all('a')`, and then using a `for` loop to iterate over `anchor_tags` and find the text for the `span` elements (with the appropriate `itemprop` attribute) which are children:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = '<a><span itemprop="foo"> TEXT I WANT </span></a> \
<label><span itemprop="foo"> DO NOT WANT </span></label> \
<a><span itemprop="foo"> I WANT THIS TOO </span></a> \
<strong><a> DO NOT WANT </a></strong> \
<label><span itemprop="foo"> DO NOT WANT </span></label>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
anchor_tags = soup.find_all('a')
for a in anchor_tags:
    for span in a.find_all('span', attrs={'itemprop': 'foo'}):
        print span.text
```

**Output**

```
 TEXT I WANT 
 I WANT THIS TOO
```